# canvas rectangles get drawn then disappear javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw

I want to have a canvas with a background image, and draw rectangles over the top. The rectangles are called hotSpots in my application. They get drawn to the canvas then quickly disappear. How can I make them stay?

appendSection() first appends a picture with appendPicture() which just appends a canvas to a div, then after that function has run, the canvas and context is made, then for every hotSpot, which there are 3 in this case, it will draw a rect, which it does, then they disappear.

```
function appendSection(theSection, list) {
        list.append('<label class="heading">' + theSection.description + '</label><br/><hr><br/>');
        if (theSection.picture) {
            appendPicture(list, theSection);
            var canvas = document.getElementById('assessmentImage');
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
             var img=new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                }
                img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ theSection.picture;
            if(theSection.allHotSpots.length > 0) {
                for( var x = 0; x < theSection.allHotSpots.length; x++) {
                    appendHotSpot(list, theSection.allHotSpots[x], theSection.thePicture, ctx);
                }
            }
        }
        appendSectionQuestions(theSection, list);
        if (theSection.allSubSections) {
            for (var x = 0; x < theSection.allSubSections.length; x++) {
                var theSectionA = theSection.allSubSections[x];
                appendSection(theSectionA, list);
            }
        }
    }

    function appendHotSpot(list, HotSpot, picture, ctx) {
        var imageWidth = document.getElementById('assessmentImage' + platform).clientWidth;
        var imageHeight = document.getElementById('assessmentImage' + platform).clientHeight;

        var xScale = imageWidth / picture.xSize;
        var yScale = imageHeight / picture.ySize;

        HotSpot.topLeft = [Math.round(HotSpot.topLeft[0] * xScale), Math.round(HotSpot.topLeft[1] * yScale)];
        HotSpot.bottomRight = [Math.round(HotSpot.bottomRight[0] * xScale), Math.round(HotSpot.bottomRight[1] * yScale)];


        var rect = {x1: HotSpot.topLeft[0], y1: HotSpot.topLeft[1], x2: HotSpot.bottomRight[0], y2: HotSpot.bottomRight[1]};



        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(rect.x1, rect.y1, rect.x2, rect.y2);

        //addRect("blue", rect);

    }

    function appendPicture(list, theSection) {


            list.append('<div id="wrapper' + platform + '" style="width:100%; text-align:center">\
                <canvas class="assessmentImageSmall" style="width:100%;" id="assessmentImage' + platform + '" align="middle" ></canvas>\
                <!--<p style="color:#666;" id="imageInstruction">Tap image to enlarge.</p>-->\
                </div>');
            $("#wrapper").kendoTouch({
                                         tap: function (e) {
                                             switchImage();
                                         }
                                     });
    }
```

Comment: Is the canvas constantly being updated every few milliseconds? If so you need to re-draw your rectangles when the canvas is updated.

Comment: If the background doesn't serve a purpose other than displaying a static image, you could just specify the background of the canvas in CSS.

Comment: Thanks @RickyAYoder your solution is also a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your rects are being drawn and then the image (which loads asynchronously) is eventually loaded and then drawn on top of the rects--making them disappear.

Put the `if(theSection.allHotSpots.length > 0` inside the onload so the image doesn't later clobber the rects.

Comment: Basically I can start drawing after the img.onload function right?